# Add same view multiple times - Reuse a layout

Tags: android, reusability

I'm developing an app that shows the weather forecast of 4 different regions, 5 days in the future. Every region displays 5 days and every day has its own data: a TextView with the name of the day, a TextView with the main weather condition for that day, an ImageView that shows the weather icon, and two TextView with the min temp and max temp for that day. Like this:

[image]

I implemented this in a SUPER AWFUL layout.xml file, treating each TextView and ImageView for all the 20 days of the 4 regions separately:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_weather_forecats_title"
            style="@style/tv_weather_11"
            android:text="@string/extended_forecast" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_fore_title_city"
            style="@style/tv_weather_6"
            android:text="@string/title_city" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/ll_weather_1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day1_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Mon"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond1_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day1_city"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day1_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day1_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day2_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Tue"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond2_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day2_city"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day2_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day2_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day3_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Wed"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond3_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day3_city"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day3_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day3_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day4_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Thu"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond4_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day4_city"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day4_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day4_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day5_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Fri"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond5_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day5_city"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day5_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day5_city"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkTextDivider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_fore_title_east"
            style="@style/tv_weather_6"
            android:text="@string/title_east" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/ll_weather_1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day1_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Mon"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond1_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day1_east"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day1_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day1_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day2_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Tue"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond2_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day2_east"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day2_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day2_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day3_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Wed"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond3_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day3_east"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day3_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day3_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day4_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Thu"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond4_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day4_east"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day4_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day4_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day5_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Fri"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond5_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day5_east"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day5_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day5_east"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkTextDivider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_fore_title_south"
            style="@style/tv_weather_6"
            android:text="@string/title_south" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/ll_weather_1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day1_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Mon"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond1_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day1_south"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day1_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day1_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day2_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Tue"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond2_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day2_south"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day2_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day2_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day3_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Wed"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond3_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day3_south"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day3_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day3_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day4_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Thu"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond4_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day4_south"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day4_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day4_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_day5_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_7"
                    android:text="Fri"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_cond5_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_8"
                    android:text="Light Rain"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_fore_ic_day5_south"
                    style="@style/iv_weather_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_broken_clouds" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_min_day5_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_9"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fore_max_day5_south"
                    style="@style/tv_weather_10"
                    android:text="15"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

On the Java file I have 100 declarations of views and use 100 lines to get the instance of the views, and another 100 set methods to set texts and images... I know, super/unbelievably awful.

This must be bad design for sure. There must be a way to put a single view (day name, condition, image, min temp and max temp) in a layout and reuse it. Any idea?

Comment: use `<include ...>` tag

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom view, encapsulating all your presentation logic and just add a number of those in your `LinearLayout`.

You will avoid the XML code duplication and you will be able to have a single, well defined widget that suits your needs. Also, this will reduce the amount of java code you need to bind your data to the existing views.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data comes from some kind of Weather Api or your own implemented database over here.

I have 2 solutions to achieve this

1. **Nested RecyclerView : Horizontal RecyclerView inside a Vertical RecyclerView**

   - you would have a horizontal vertical layout

     [image]

     This layout would be repeated 7 times for each day.
   - Your Vertical RecyclerView would be a collection of such Horizontal RecyclerView (for regions)
   - Use a ArrayList and Populate your RecyclerView.

This is a **cleaner** but a **Complicated** way to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

2. **Single Vertical RecyclerView**

   - Create a single layout with a Horizontal LinearLayout storing your Views.

     Layout Structure would be like this (repeated 7 times)

     LinearLayout(Horizontal)

     - LinearLayout(Vertical)
     - 5 Textviews
   - Populate your Recyclerview with a Arraylist.

Personally i would go for the first one, but you can choose anything that helps you.